# query different rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet of creditors and there is a checkbox on each entry next to total price column. When I receive the payment I check the checkbox. Now I am trying to query all the unpaid creditors to another sheet but I don't know how to query creditor name when the checkbox is on another row. I can query same row entries.
here is how it looks like

| Name | Items | Payment Received (Checkbox) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | chips | TRUE |
| Joe | beer | FALSE |
| Katrine | chips |  |
|  | fruits | FALSE |
| Bob | coke |  |
|  | vegies | TRUE |
| Adrine | chips |  |
|  | beer | FALSE |

I tried QUERY. But didn't help. It just shows same row items. What happens here is first column customers buy the items on second column and if customer pays then third column becomes TRUE and if it is a credit, then it is FALSE. And if customer buys more than 1 item, then the TRUE value will be next to the last item of second column. So what I am trying to achieve is, I am trying to query or whatever somehow filter those customers who haven't paid their payment. –

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Tried `FILTER` or `QUERY`?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: I tried QUERY. But didn't help. It just shows same row items. What happens here is first column customers buy the items on second column and if customer pays then third column becomes TRUE and if it is a credit, then it is FALSE. And if customer buys more than 1 item, then the TRUE value will be next to the last item of second column. So what I am trying to achieve is, I am trying to query or whatever somehow filter those customers who haven't paid their payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear what you need, but if it's the value in col1 to repeat down, with a query pulling out data where col 3 is false, then try this:

```
=index(query({if(B:B<>"",vlookup(row(A:A),query({row(A:A),A:A},"where Col2 is not null",0),2,1),),B:C},"select Col1,Col2 where Col3 = false",1))
```

You can alter the query to only select Col1 if you only want the Name.

[image]

Comment: hey this almost fixed my problem. can i share my google sheet with you..? 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IixL4E_uow8qKypdVQQ2GUKZSIDsz30tGummX_tXjCg/edit?usp=sharing
here it is.. there's a sheet called pending, i am trying to query all the pending creditors name with date and amount there. can you try it

Comment: Now only 1 problem, instead of customer name it is showing another column.

Comment: I can't share the sheet. Can you post screengrabs of the relevant details?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if the table is formatted in [first-normal-form](/questions/tagged/first-normal-form). But here, for each name( using `MAP`),we get the corresponding last checkbox per group using `XMATCH`'s wildcard match and `OFFSET`. Once, we got  the checkbox, we use `FILTER` to filter out what's not needed.

```
=FILTER(A2:A9,
  MAP(C2:C9,A2:A9,
    LAMBDA(checkbox,name,
      IF(OR(checkbox,name=""),
        ,
        NOT(IFNA(
          OFFSET(checkbox,
            XMATCH("*",OFFSET(name,1,0,5,1),2)-1,0
          ),
        C9)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

- Since, `XMATCH` can't find the last checkbox, as there's no  corresponding value, we reference the last checkbox at `C9` manually.
- For each name, `OFFSET(...,5)` gets 5 rows to get the last checkbox per group. If there are a maximum of 10 items per group, you have to change `5` to `10`.